# create a dropdown list for month and year and selected in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a "search by month and year " feature and have listed the months and year in a drop-down (select) field.so far this is working perfect but i need to show selected (month and year) after submitting the form .but i unable to do how to get selected year and month in drop down.below is my php JavaScript code .anyone help me how to solve

below is the two dropdowns for month year .the month and year sholud be shown as selected.

```
<select name="month" class="form-control" >

<?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i)
    {
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $label = date('F ', $time);
    $value = date('m', $time);
    printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>', $value, $label);
    }

?>
</select>
<select name="year" class="form-control">
      <?php

for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i)
    {
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
    $value = date('Y', $time);
    $label = date('Y ', $time);
    printf('<option value="%s" selected="selected">%s</option>', $value, $label);
    }

?>
</select>
```

so far this is working perfect but i need to show selected (month and year) after submitting the form .but i unable to do how to get selected year and month in drop down.below is my php java-script code .anyone help me how to solve it?

Comment: did you store the value in the database after submitting the form?
you need to get the submitted values here from DB or from the post array or store in the session and get it here.

Comment: no need to store the month and year values in database .but i am using it for filtering perpose i mean based on the year and month i get data soo when choose perticular month and year in dropdown those year and month should be selected

Comment: what form method are you using?

Comment: so the form is submitting on the same page?
you can get the form submitted value using $_REQUEST['month']

Comment: am using get method yes on the same page .the url after choosing the year and month like this   http://localhost/cilias/welcome/getReports?course=3121&filter_options=3&month=03&year=2013            but in dropdown it should be 3rd month and 2013 .but it is not happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the value held in the `$_REQUEST` array to find the value of each select menu. However as you have stated the form uses `GET` it is preferable to then use values from the `$_GET` array as this leaves the POST method free and will not affect the selected values should there be any POSTing of data ( ajax etc )

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="month" class="form-control">
                <?php
                    $month = !empty( $_GET['month'] ) ? $_GET['month'] : 0;
                    for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i) {
                        $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
                        $label = date('F ', $time);
                        $value = date('m', $time);

                        $selected = ( $value==$month ) ? ' selected=true' : '';

                        printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $value, $selected, $label );
                    }
                ?>
            </select>

            <select name="year" class="form-control">
                <?php

                    $year = !empty( $_GET['year'] ) ? $_GET['year'] : 0;

                    for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i)  {
                        $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
                        $value = date('Y', $time);
                        $label = date('Y ', $time);

                        $selected = ( $value==$year ) ? ' selected=true' : '';

                        printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>', $value, $selected, $label);
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i put $_GET instead of $_REQUEST for month it is working but for year it is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<select name="month" class="form-control" >
<?php
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; ++$i){
        $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
        $label = date('F ', $time);
        $value = date('m', $time);
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'" ';
        if((isset($_GET['month']))&&($value==$_GET['month']))echo 'selected';// Check if form submitted or not. select the month if yes
        echo '>'.$label.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<select name="year" class="form-control">
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i){
        $time = strtotime(sprintf('-%d years', $i));
        $value = date('Y', $time);
        echo '<option value="'.$value.'" ';
        if((isset($_GET['year']))&&($value==$_GET['year']))echo 'selected';// Check if form submitted or not. select the year if yes
        echo '>'.$value.'</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

For month code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i){
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $label = date('F ', $time);
    $value = date('m', $time);
    $sleceted='';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['month']){
        $sleceted=$_REQUEST['month']== $value?'selected:selected':'';
    }
    printf('<option value="%s" '.$sleceted.'>%s</option>', $value, $label);
}
```

for year code

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 12; ++$i){
    $time = strtotime(sprintf('+%d months', $i));
    $label = date('F ', $time);
    $value = date('m', $time);
    $sleceted='';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['year']){
        $sleceted=$_REQUEST['year']== $value?'selected:selected':'';
    }
    printf('<option value="%s" '.$sleceted.'>%s</option>', $value, $label);
}
```

Comment: i tried above code too but still selected not working